# Fixed parameter estimates of parent factors in a nested design

Tags: spss, fixed-effects-model, estimators, nested-data

**Summary**: What is happening with parameter estimates of factors that are the 'parents' of nested factors?

**Data**: My analysis involves testing the effect of different parameter settings for automatic wave detection. My data consist of several different recordings (from different people), re-analysed using different detection settings. My goal is find out which parameters matter for certain outcomes.

I have about 20 parameters I'm adjusting but a simplified version of the syntax that would recreate the issue would be:

```
MIXED wave_density BY amplitude_criteria WITH amplitude_threshold
/FIXED amplitude_criteria amplitude_threshold(amplitude_criteria) | SSTYPE(3)
/METHOD=REML
/PRINT=SOLUTION
/REPEATED amplitude_criteria*amplitude_threshold | SUBJECT(participant_ID) COVTYPE(DIAG)
/EMMEANS=TABLES(amplitude_criteria)
```

Here *amplitude_criteria* (coded as 1 and 2), is whether I used a relative measure for each participant (measured in deviations from the mean microVolts), or an absolute threshold (directly microVolts), for all participants, and the *amplitude_threshold* actually specifies the threshold used. *Amplitude_threshold* is nested because the values are not comparable between the levels of *amplitude_criteria*.

**Problem**: Given that the grand mean density found is about 10 (waves per minute), with a small standard error of around 1; and amplitude_threshold estimates indicate a changes of around 0.5 for every step in threshold (as expected), the estimate for *amplitude_criteria* of 40 when changing between relative or absolute methods is ridiculous since the wave density never varies that much. When I look at the 'estimated means' for *amplitude_criteria* output the difference between methods is less than 1 (what is expected).

**Question**: So how do I interpret this value of 40? This can't be the expected change or slope when switching between *amplitude_criteria* methods of 1 and 2.

As mentioned, I actually have about 20 parameter factors to be estimated and the ones that are not nested have expected estimates. I have another 'parent' factor which also gives an unreasonable parameter estimate (but good estimated means), so I feel strongly this has to do with the fact that its the parent of a nested factor, but I have no idea what to do with the estimates when reporting them now.

Thanks for any insight or help anyone can provide!